# C# UWP Hamburger Menu Item Language Change

Tags: c#, uwp, hamburger-menu

(I'm so beginner in UWP)
I made a little app with Visual Template Studio and I'm using this code, to change between two languages.

```
        private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem==hun) 
        {
            ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "hu-hu";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
            Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());               
        }
        else if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem == eng)
        {
            ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-us";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
            Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());
        }           
    }
```

But this doesn't change the items' language in the hamburger menu, which are only "MainPage" and "Settings".
Could you guys show me a method to change the language there too?

Comment: Please check if you have done [Globalization and localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/globalizing-portal) for your hamburger's items.

Comment: Thank you, that was my mistake.

Comment: So, it seemed that you've solved your issue. What's the solution?

Comment: just missed the usings